# Groupby one column and apply 2 columns into list pandas

Tags: python, pandas

i have a dataframe

```
id  name value    flag
1    a     x        F
1    b     y        A
2    c     z        B
3    d     m        Q
```

if i want to groupby id and put value column into a new column as a list.

i can do

```
df.groupby('id')['value'].apply(list).reset_index()
```

is there any way where i can do groupby by 'id'  but put 2 column's(name and value) into list.

```
my desired output


id    col
 1    [[a,x],[b,y]]
 2    [[c,z]]
 3    [[d,m]]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Convert columns to `numpy array` by [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) and then to `list`s in `groupby` or sepearately to new `Series`:

```
df = df.groupby('id')
       .apply(lambda x: x[['name','value']].values.tolist())
       .reset_index(name='col')
print (df)
   id               col
0   1  [[a, x], [b, y]]
1   2          [[c, z]]
2   3          [[d, m]]
```

Or:

```
s = pd.Series(df[['name','value']].values.tolist(), index=df.index)
df = s.groupby(df['id']).apply(list).reset_index(name='col')
print (df)
   id               col
0   1  [[a, x], [b, y]]
1   2          [[c, z]]
2   3          [[d, m]]
```

Also if no problem with tuples in `list`s:

```
s = pd.Series(list(zip(df['name'],df['value'])), index=df.index)
df = s.groupby(df['id']).apply(list).reset_index(name='col')
print (df)
   id               col
0   1  [(a, x), (b, y)]
1   2          [(c, z)]
2   3          [(d, m)]
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `zip` in `apply` i.e

```
df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: list(zip(x['name'],x['value'])))

id
1    [(a, x), (b, y)]
2            [(c, z)]
3            [(d, m)]
dtype: object
```

To match your exact output use `to_frame` and `reset_index` i.e

```
df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: list(zip(x['name'],x['value']))).to_frame('col').reset_index()

  id               col
0   1  [(a, x), (b, y)]
1   2          [(c, z)]
2   3          [(d, m)]
```

Comment: `df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: list(zip(x['name'],x['value']))).reset_index(name='col')` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use numpy's `stack` function to convert the two columns to one column of lists, and then use pandas' own `groupby` function.

Imports and building dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [[1,'a','x','F'],
     [1,'b','y','A'],
     [2,'c','z','B'],
     [3,'d','m','Q']],
    columns=['id','name','value','flag']
).set_index('id')
```

The function:

```
df.assign(col=list(np.stack(df[['name','value']].values))) \
    .groupby(level=0)['col'].apply(list).to_frame()
```

Which returns:

```
                 col
id                 
1   [[a, x], [b, y]]
2           [[c, z]]
3           [[d, m]]
```

Comment: `set_index('id')`? but there isn't a id column

Comment: @Bharath oops, missed that in the copy-paste, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Fixing a previous errant solution

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"i" : [i % 3 for i in range(20)], "x" : range(20), "y" : range(20)}) # Init a dummy dframe
df = df.groupby('i')\
        .apply(lambda row: tuple(zip(row['x'], row['y'])))\
        .reset_index()
```

Comment: Yep, forgot to include that. That adjusted the expected behavior.
Learned something new today about applying on grouped dataframes.

Comment: That would make mine and yours same :( since you posted an answer early editing now make others feel like I copied your answer.